# How to Import Image from PILLOW In Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, python-imaging-library, jupyter

I am trying to import Image from PILLOW.

```
    from PILLOW import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
Undefined function 'from' for input arguments of type 'char'.

>> import PIL.Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
Error using import
Import argument 'PIL.Image' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

> Undefined function 'from' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I keep getting the same error. Am I using the wrong import statement?

EDIT:
I noticed something else. when i browse through my  C:/ drive and look inside the folders where Pip, and PIL ,etc is. There is nothing inside them. Even when i copy a file with stuff to that area, and open that new file, i cant see any of the stuff inside. When i copy it though, and the green bar goes it shows data being transferred.

The Code:
https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/alexmill-website_notebooks-fcqkeh7a/notebooks/fourier-spinning-circles.ipynb#

Example:

```
    enter code here
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
# Main imports/Initialization
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import animation, rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from copy import deepcopy
from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from copy import deepcopy
​
# Default figure size in notebook
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6,6)
matplotlib.rcParams['image.aspect'] = 'equal'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7c75157a7886> in <module>
      7 from IPython.display import HTML
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
     10 import requests
     11 from io import BytesIO

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: Is this a question about how to load image in matlab (into whatever form) or how to load images from "PILLOW"? Does [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) not serve your purpose?

Comment: not sure. i am using a prebuilt notebook, and its more compelx than just this. It imports a few things, but the import command doesnt seem to work. Why does from not work?

Comment: If your answer to the above is "not sure", you need to do more work.
Please consult [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [minimal, self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) examples.

Comment: What does this have to do with matlab? if you are typing these commands into matlab they will definitely not work

Comment: please explain what you mean. Is the file linked above not supposed to be run in matlab?!?

Comment: Guess you where right. I don't know why i thought it was matlab. But why does it not run on Binder/Jupyer either. IPython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your [binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/alexmill/website_notebooks/master?filepath=fourier-spinning-circles.ipynb) doesn't work is because your `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
matplotlib==2.0.2
requests==2.20.0
Pillow==5.0.0
numpy==1.13.0
scipy==0.19.0
pandas==0.20.2
scikit-learn==0.18.1
tzlocal-1.5.1
```

This line:

> tzlocal-1.5.1

Probably breaks the binder dependency install. Another thing is that these are very specific versions that might generate too specific dependencies (ref. [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binder/issues/121)). I recommend changing it to this:

```
matplotlib
requests
pillow
numpy
scipy
pandas
scikit-learn
tzlocal
```

At least your binder started working when I did that.

Locally you will just have to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with an admin command prompt and then your local Jupyter installation should automatically work, at least it did when I cloned your notebook to a Windows VM.

Comment: ill give it a shot, give me a sec. What does Sudo do?

Comment: I still get the same response: Import argument 'PIL.Image' cannot be found or cannot be imported.

Comment: I noticed something else. when i browse through my  C:/ drive and look inside the folders where Pip, and PIL ,etc is. There is nothing inside them. Even when i copy a file with stuff to that area, and open that new file, i cant see any of the stuff inside. When i copy it though, and the green bar goes it shows data being transferred.

Comment: https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/alexmill-website_notebooks-fcqkeh7a/notebooks/fourier-spinning-circles.ipynb#

Comment: If you take a look at the link above, the code doesnt even work online let alone my PC.

Comment: Yes, i did exactly what you did before. It agree it seems to be something with matlab not finding it. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: pyversion

       version: ''
    executable: ''
       library: ''
          home: ''
      isloaded: 0

Comment: Alright so everything is installed correctly now. How do i import PIL.Image?

Comment: Import argument 'PIL.Image' cannot be found or cannot be imported.

Comment: wait, so your telling me this isn't Matlab: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/alexmill/website_notebooks/master?filepath=fourier-spinning-circles.ipynb                  IS it IPython!!

Comment: So i guess my real question is: Why does it not work in Jupyter (The online website) !!!!!!